# Copy file from bucket1 to bucket2 in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am using the following code to copy file from one storage in my cloud function:

```
exports.copyFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const srcBucketName = 'bucket1';
const srcFilename = object.name;
const destBucketName = 'bucket2';
const destFilename = 'example.png';

storage
.bucket(srcBucketName)
.file(srcFilename)
.copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFilename))
.then(() => {
  console.log(
    `gs://${srcBucketName}/${srcFilename} copied to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFilename}.`
  );
  return console.log('done!');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
  })
 });
```

I am getting following error in log:

```
ERROR: { ApiError: Not Found
at Object.parseHttpRespBody....}
```

Not sure what's missing. Any help?

Comment: My bad. `srcBucketName` needs to be accessed in function. Hazards of Google docs and copy paste habits :(...`exports.copyFile = functions.storage.bucket(srcBucketName).object().onFinalize((object)`

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer? thanks!

Comment: @Iñigo Submitted! This works

Answer (score 5):

```
const srcBucketName = 'bucket1';  
exports.copyFile = functions.storage.bucket(srcBucketName).object().onFinalize((object) => {
  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();  
  const srcFilename = object.name;
  const destBucketName = 'bucket2';
  const destFilename = 'file2';      
  storage
  .bucket(srcBucketName)
  .file(srcFilename)
  .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFilename))
  .then(() => {
    console.log(
      `gs://${srcBucketName}/${srcFilename} copied to gs://${destBucketName}/${destFilename}.`
    );
    return console.log('done!');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
})
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In case anyone receives an `Admin SDK ERROR: Expression has type void` its because of `return console.log('done!')`. Console.log does not return a value so you have to put the `console.log('done!')` and the `return` on two separate lines.